# Rename package name of .apk

Tags: package, apk

I am trying to install `WhatsApp.apk` twice on my Android. I already got a readable `androidmanifest.xml` using `apktool`. I heard that I only have to change the package name in that xml and I can install the app. Indeed it's not blocking anymore when I change the package name but fails during the installation. So I guess there are other files where I need to change the package name.

Is there a way to import the project to Eclipse to have it change the package names or how can I completely change the package name `com.whatsapp` in all files to another one? Or: Do you have a simpler solution to install 2 whatsapp on one device?

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I'm trying the same thing because whatsapp is preinstalled on my phone but I want to reduce permissions and installing with the same name ends in the famous package name conflict message. Did you checkout this? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19935/how-to-keep-two-versions-of-an-app-installed/20793#20793

Answer (score 0):

You can change name thorough small files..open all small files into notepad++ 
replace `com/whatsapp` to `com/yourpackagename`

Do same thing in `androidmanifest.xml` & 
replace `com.whatsapp` to `com.urpackagename`

Also repeat the same thing for `layout folder`

Comment: Did you try this? Java files are compiled binary code, editing them in a text editor will destroy them, especially if the package name length changes